# Experiencing java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, photo

I am currently following this https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html tutorial and I am getting that error when using this method

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

I have tried other solution online and none worked for me. I also have added the proper permissions

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace associated with this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: If version is greater than or euqals to 23, @CleoCortez you have to ask for runtime permissions. If you just want to test  goes to app permissions and see if they are enabled or not